# React Hook Form doesn't clear the file upload field properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form in a project with a form where I have to upload a file. Here's the snippet of the input field:

```
      <div className='mb-3'>
        <label className='form-label' htmlFor='xmlFile'>
          XML File
        </label>
        <input
          type='file'
          className='form-control'
          id='xmlFile'
          name='xmlFile'
          {...register('xmlFile')}
        />
        {watch().xmlFile ? <Button onClick={() => handleFieldReset('xmlFile')}>Empty</Button> : ''}
        {errors.xmlFile && <p>{errors.xmlFile.message}</p>}
      </div>
```

I'm using the watch API so that I can keep track of the value in order to conditionally render the button for clearing the input.
Here's the handleFieldReset function tied to the onClick:

```
  const handleFieldReset = (field) => {
    resetField(field)
  }
```

The problem is that when I clear the input, it clears the value but it doesn't clear the file name from the input field rendered on screen:

[image]

I've also tried to replace the resetField function with `setValue(nameOfTheField, '')` without any luck. Tried to look online for a solution but didn't find anything relatable.

Comment: Can you mention which version of `react-hook-form` are you using?

Comment: @SanketShah 7.24.2

Comment: I've found a workaround by adding document.getElementById(field).value = ''; to handleFieldReset as second instruction. Is this considered a bad practice in React?